# Are data back up solutions shown on the network diagram?

Tags: design, backups

I have started my first job and apart from designing a network (which I have done) I'm to decide about back up solutions. I use Visio for diagramming but I have no idea whether a data back up should be in the diagram or not and how to do it.
I have a database servers and I assume there should be something to show their back up storage.
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would approach this by thinking of the conceptual layers: "backups" are an application that uses the network. So if you're going to include a representation of backups, then you should have all(most?) network using applications shown. So if that's what the diagram is about, then yes, include backups. If it is, for example, a physical wiring diagram, then there'd be no applications shown.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I probably did not make myself clear (sorry for my English). By backups I mean data backups of e.g. database servers.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant. "backups" is an application, like "web servers" or "file servers", which use the network.

Comment: Oh, right. Also assuming I have a Web server or a DB server, how the simplest backup should look like? I cannot find anything to quickly resolve that. Thank you

Comment: how about a [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=backup+diagram&hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enUS358US358&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=RV88T5GkPIqXiAKC5JmNAQ&ved=0CEIQsAQ&biw=1353&bih=942)?

Comment: yes, though I mainly want to understand, it is hard if I do not have the foundation. I tried to find a network diagram (classic) with backup but these are different.

Answer (score 3):

I create several different layers of diagrams. This is required to completely document a network. I keep application specific information off of physical diagram. My physical diagram usually includes IP addresses as well, and some basic info about the devices themselves (Make, model, firmware, etc). I then make logical network diagrams that include applications, like Exchange, SQL, Backups, etc. Finally, I'll usually include a logical application diagram that explains rules for services, open ports, how clients connect, etc (For those applications listed above, like Exchange RPC/HTTP, Autodiscover, SMTP, etc). And I also have a logical application diagram for the backup server, saying what is backed up, when (schedules), how (agent, local or remote, xcopy, rsync, etc).